# Superclass constructor calling an overridden method in a subclass - whose instance variables are referred to?

Tags: java, constructor, overriding

I have been looking at a code where superclass constructor calls a polymorphic method.

Now, do you know if the method startUp of the class OrderManager works with the variable ior of its own class or of CorbaComponent class?

Thanks

```
class CorbaComponent {
    String ior;
    CorbaComponent() {startUp("IOR");}
    void startUp(String s){ior = s;}
    void print() {System.out.println(ior);}
}

class OrderManager extends CorbaComponent {
    OrderManager(){}
    void startUp(String s) {ior = getIORfromURL(s);}
    String getIORfromURL(String s) {return "URL://" + s;}
}

public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {start(new OrderManager());}
    static void start (CorbaComponent cc) {cc.print();}
}
```

Comment: There's only one instance, so there's only one variable. What happened when you tried your code, and what confused you about that? It's not really clear what you're asking here. I would *strongly* encourage you to format your code more conventionally in the future, btw.

Comment: To add to that, you should _not_ be calling an overridable method from your constructor. It runs before the subclass constructor does, and you can easily introduce issues of accessing non-initialized variables in the overriding method.

Answer (score 0):

In java, field extension is not possible. If you declare a field it is available by definition according to its scope. If you declare a secondary field in an extending class it will be logical and acceptable by java.
As to answer your question, in this case since you are calling the method `print` from the structure of `CorbaComponent`, you will see the value of `ior` defined in `CorbaComponent`. Since there is no field inheritance, the definition od `ior` is limited to the subclass `OrderManager`.
If you intend to use your own variable (not to be confused - since there is no field inheritance). You must extend the `print` method in your subclass.